# How to Extract the URL from A String in PHP?

Tags: php, simplexml, flickr

I'm using PHP's "simplexml_load_file" to get some data from Flickr.

My goal is to get the photo url.

I'm able to get the following value (assigned to PHP variable):

```
<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/people/19725893@N00/">codewrecker</a> posted a photo:</p>

<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/19725893@N00/2302759205/" title="Santa Monica Pier"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2298/2302759205_4fb109f367_m.jpg" width="180" height="240" alt="Santa Monica Pier" /></a></p>
```

**How can I extract just this part of it?**

```
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2298/2302759205_4fb109f367_m.jpg
```

Just in case it helps, here's the code I'm working with:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=19725893@N00&lang=en-us&format=xml&tags=carousel");
foreach($xml->entry as $child) {
    $flickr_content = $child->content; // gets html including img url
    // how can I get the img url from "$flickr_content"???
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably get away with using a regular expression for this, assuming that the way the HTML is formed is pretty much going to stay the same, e.g.:

```
if (preg_match('/<img src="([^"]+)"/i', $string, $matches)) {
    $imageUrl = $matches[1];   
}
```

This is fairly un-robust, and if the HTML is going to change (e.g. the order of parameters in the `<img>` tag, risk of malformed HTML etc.), you would be better off using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

It's not solving your problem(and probably total overkill), but worth mentioning because I've used the library on 2 projects and it's well written.

phpFlickr - http://phpflickr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:  Combination of substr and strpos to extract first the  tag and then the src='...' value, and finally the target string.

Slightly more difficult way (BUT MUCH MORE ROBUST): Use an XML parsing library such as simpleXML

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful.  I enjoy using xpath to cut through the XML I get back from SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=19725893@N00&lang=en-us&format=xml&tags=carousel", NULL, True);
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');  //use xpath on the XML to find the img tags

foreach($images as $image){  
    echo $image['src'] ;  //here is the image URL
}
?>
```